# Dimension of $\mathbb{F}^n$

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $\mathbb{F}$ be a field. Consider the vector space of $\mathbb{F}^n$ over $\mathbb{F}$ for some positive integer $n$.
Is the dimension of $\mathbb{F}^n$ necessarily $n$?

Comment: Yes, and it's easy to show a basis.

Comment: Let $e_k$ be the vector of zeros except for $1$ in the $k$th position. Then the $e_k$ are linearly independent and span the entire space.

Comment: @Omnitic: When considering the complex numbers as a vector space over the complex numbers, **any** non-zero vector will span the whole space.

Comment: yes, sorry for the inconvinience guys

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. It is true. The following vectors are a basis vectors:

$e_{1} = (1,0,...0), ..., e_{k} = (0,...0,1,0,..,0) \quad (1 \text{on $ k $th position}), ...e_{n} = (0,...0,1)$

Each of these vectors in a $n-$tuple.

Comment: What do you mean by $n*1$?

Comment: I'd object to the claim that those vectors are *the* basis vectors. They form *a* basis. One of many different.

Comment: @celtschk Correct. I did not mean uniqueness when I used the article 'the'.

Comment: @Omnitic Why do you need to write every element of the field as $n^{*}1$?

Comment: @Vishal sorry I got it.

Comment: @Vishal: But "the" implies uniqueness.